# The HOST variable in /etc/sudoers

Tags: sudo, etc

suppose `mymachine:/etc/sudoers` includes the line

```
joe  someremotehost = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

but `someremotehost:/etc/sudoers` does **not** say anything special about `joe`, then what effect does the above line have?

Answer (score 14):

In its default configuration, `sudo` looks in the `sudoers` file on the local machine (i.e., on the machine upon which it is invoked) to determine what to do - it doesn't contact another host to find out what *it* would permit, so in this case, the `joe someremotehost` line on your local machine would not affect the operation of `sudo` on `someremotehost`. And since it specifies a hostname restriction, `sudo` on your local machine would ignore the rule, because the hostname in the config doesn't match the hostname `sudo` gets from the C library.

The `sudoers` file syntax allows you to specify hostname restrictions so that managing policy for a large group of hosts is as easy as editing the file in one place, and then pushing it out to all hosts in the administrative domain.

Comment: Best to keep `/etc/sudoers` untouched (don't mess up `root`) and push-sync a central config folder to `/etc/sudoers.d/` on every machine, right?

Comment: That would mean that keeping the ALL instead of a specific host name makes the sudoers no less secure, if only employed locally on one box, right?

Answer (score 3):

Effectively nothing. The file on the remote host is never consulted, but the local file only gives permission on the other host, not on this host.

Answer (score 3):

When using puppet, or sharing the file with many hosts in your network, then the HOST section becomes more relevant.