# What does "site-wide" mean?

Tags: directory-structure, terminology, standard

I'm reading `man hier`, which says:

> /etc
>
> Contains  configuration  files  which  are local to the machine. Some larger software packages, like X11, can have their own subdirectories below /etc. **Site-wide** configuration files may be placed here  or  in  /usr/etc. Nevertheless,  programs  should  always look for these files in /etc and you may have links for these files to /usr/etc.

What does "site-wide" mean?

Is it synonymous with "system-wide", that is, for all users on the system?

Answer (score 2):

The `hier` manpage is largely based on [the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html), and searching the full text of that document leads to this text (emphasis added):

> #### 4.11. /usr/share : Architecture-independent data
>
> [...]
>
> This hierarchy is intended to be shareable among all architecture
> platforms of a given OS; thus, for example, *a site with i386, Alpha,
> and PPC platforms* might maintain a single /usr/share directory that is
> centrally-mounted. Note, however, that /usr/share is generally not
> intended to be shared by different OSes or by different releases of
> the same OS.

From that and the text quoted in the question, we can conclude that a *site* is some sort of logical grouping of systems; say, the PCs in a University lab. The entirety of `/usr` is supposedly shareable between hosts of the same platform; `/usr/share` and `/usr/etc` can be shared between hosts of differing platforms. The quote in the question says that configuration files shared across hosts in a site can be put in `/etc` or in `/usr/etc`. One example of such a configuration file is `/etc/sudoers`, which explicitly supports this by allowing rules to specify the host that they should apply to (see, e.g., [Why does the sudoers file contain IP addresses?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/150346/70524) or [The HOST variable in /etc/sudoers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71684/70524)).